# Multiselect Issue

Tags: apex, visualforce

I had a line item with a multiselect feature. It was working and saving fine but without any code change all the sudden it does not save correctly, if I select 3 items it only highlights two items and so on. Not sure why, is this a known bug of some sorts, where should I check to find the problem?

VF

```
 <apex:SelectList rendered="{!contains(di.dataType, 'Multipicklist')}" size="5" value=" 
                                                 {!di.multiSelect}" multiselect="true">
         <apex:SelectOptions value="{!di.pickList}" />
 </apex:SelectList>
```

Apex

```
 public String[] multiSelect {get; set;}
```

Method used to create the list options, which works

```
 private List<SelectOption> createLists(string content) {
        List<SelectOption> pickList = new List<SelectOption>();   
        List<String> options = content.split(';');             

        for (String value : options) 
            pickList.add(new SelectOption(value, value));   

        return pickList;  
    } 



 if ( dataType.equals('Multipicklist')) {
    //content is the list of selection options retrieved from another object.
            object.pickList = createLists(content);
    }
```

These are code snippets of the relevant parts and it is fairly safe to assume the other components are working.

If anyone can offer suggestions it would be greatly appreciated. This link kind of illustrates my bug as well: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T21lAAC
//additional comments
on Save

Stores the selected values in Value__c

When I load them again after save and refresh I use this code:

```
//Iterates through each line item
public String[] multiSelect {get; set;} // stores the selected multiselect values
//

if (datatype = 'Multipicklist')
{       
        //value__c is the salesforce field where I store my selected values.
        subClassObject.multiSelect = salesforceObject.Value__C.split(';');

}
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Please post your code so we can help.

Comment: added more details

Comment: By "highlight" do you mean that when you click on three, only two move across? Or that three are selected but the controller only saves two options? If that is the case, then please post the method that executes the DML, where you save the value of the List<String> multiSelect to a record.

Comment: From debugging I noticed that all three values are saved in the controller but only two are highlighted as the selected value once I press save, so when I press save again, it saves two values and only highlights one as selected. This does not happen when I choose any combination which includeds the very first value in my list. So say I my options are 1-5. If I select 2,3,4 they are saved in the controller but only 3,4 are highlighted after the save.

Comment: Also by highlighted i mean that it shows which values have been selected.

Comment: Also like to add that it was working perfectly before, I did not even make code changes, so I am really confused about what happened.

Comment: Sounds like something is going wrong with the page reading the record on refresh. You may need to do a complete refresh (setRedirect(true)) to get that done. Are you sure you're reading the record correctly?

Comment: I will check again and let you know.

Comment: It seems to be reading correctly. My Issue is similar to thishttps://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T21lAAC

Comment: setredirect did not help either

Comment: also, if I select the first option and any other combination with the first option, there is not a problem. So if my options ar 1-5 and I select 1 and any of the other 4 numbers it saves and works fine.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a problem with how you are processing the picklist. when you say "3 values are saved in the controller" not sure what that means. If you debug the select list values at the time you save, are the 3 selected values still in the variable?  How are you converting them back to the ; delimited value for saving, and how are you parsing the "existing record" again after the save to get the selected values?

Comment: On Save, all three selected values are stored in the variable as per the debug logs. After I save and the table of line items refresh, thats when the highlight problem occurs. This is when it only highlights 2 but even at this point, if I do not click save again, the variable still has 3 selected variables store although it shows 2 highlighted. I added some additional info at bottom of the post. Please take a look.

Comment: In a 'broken' scenario where you've selected three items and clicked save, what is the value that is in the `salesforceObject.Value__C` field in the database at that time? (Presuming that it only shows two of the three previously selected values as `selected` in the UI)

Comment: At that time,all three items are in the Value__c field in the database. Is this what you mean?